# Is it possible using video as texture for GL in iOS?

Tags: video, ios, opengl-es, textures

Is it possible using video (pre-rendered, compressed with H.264) as texture for GL in iOS?

If possible, how to do it? And any playback quality/frame-rate or limitations?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As of iOS 4.0, you can use `AVCaptureDeviceInput` to get the camera as a device input and connect it to a `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` with any object you like set as the delegate. By setting a 32bpp BGRA format for the camera, the delegate object will receive each frame from the camera in a format just perfect for handing immediately to `glTexImage2D` (or `glTexSubImage2D` if the device doesn't support non-power-of-two textures; I think the MBX devices fall into this category).

There are a bunch of frame size and frame rate options; at a guess you'll have to tweak those depending on how much else you want to use the GPU for. I found that a completely trivial scene with just a textured quad showing the latest frame, redrawn only exactly when a new frame arrives on an iPhone 4, was able to display that device's maximum 720p 24fps feed without any noticeable lag. I haven't performed any more thorough benchmarking than that, so hopefully someone else can advise.

In principle, per the API, frames can come back with some in-memory padding between scanlines, which would mean some shuffling of contents before posting off to GL so you do need to implement a code path for that. In practice, speaking purely empirically, it appears that the current version of iOS never returns images in that form so it isn't really a performance issue.

EDIT: it's now very close to three years later. In the interim Apple has released iOS 5, 6 and 7. With 5 they introduced `CVOpenGLESTexture` and `CVOpenGLESTextureCache`, which are now the smart way to pipe video from a capture device into OpenGL. Apple supplies sample code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011222), from which the particularly interesting parts are in `RippleViewController.m`, specifically its `setupAVCapture` and `captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection:` — see lines 196–329. Sadly the terms and conditions prevent a duplication of the code here without attaching the whole project but the step-by-step setup is:

1. create a `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate` and an `AVCaptureSession`;
2. grab a suitable `AVCaptureDevice` for video;
3. create an `AVCaptureDeviceInput` with that capture device;
4. attach an `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` and tell it to call you as a sample buffer delegate.

Upon receiving each sample buffer:

1. get the `CVImageBufferRef` from it;
2. use `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` to get Y and UV `CVOpenGLESTextureRef`s from the CV image buffer;
3. get texture targets and names from the CV OpenGLES texture refs in order to bind them;
4. combine luminance and chrominance in your shader.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I'll dig it.

Comment: It's only just about 200 lines to tie the whole thing together; sorry for not posting code - I've tackled the problem only while at work so am contractually barred from posting what I have. But it's really trivial stuff and I definitely spent a lot longer figuring out which were the appropriate classes in the documentation than I did coding.

Comment: My blog post about using 32BPP images as textures in OpenGL, includes xcode project and source code:

http://www.modejong.com/blog/post7_load_opengl_textures_with_alpha_channel_on_ios/index.html

Comment: @Tommy all the answers on this topic on SO right now are "it's easy. I'm not going to show you how. It's easy. Just dig in the APIs. Yeah". I appreciate you wrote something quickly, but that was 3 years ago, and all SO has right now are terrible answers on this topic.

Comment: @Adam since iOS 5 (about a year after my original answer) Apple has provided built-in functionality to commute `CVImageBuffer`s into OpenGL and has supplied a sample project; I've added a link as well as a more detailed breakdown of the steps involved.

Comment: @Tommy - that's awesome, thanks! None of the other SO answers I saw mentioned any of that. Looks like a huge improvement :)

Comment: @Tommy - Apple's sample project is awful - it wastes time making a complex graphical effect that makes it impossible to re-use the code in a normal app. I've spent hours trying to remove the useless bits, but something buried in there is necessary to make the main code work, and I can't figure out what :(.

Comment: @Tommy I followed your answer and dig it , i found GPUImage and make some demo but i got a problem is the render frame not the same time , could you tell me how can i fix it ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36290137/gpuimage-render-video-as-texture-but-not-the-same-time

Answer (score 0):

Use [RosyWriter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/RosyWriter/Introduction/Intro.html) for a MUCH better example of how to do OpenGL video rendering. Performance is very good, especially if you reduce the framerate (~10% at 1080P/30, >=5% at 1080P/15.