# Vuforia: it is possible play a Movie texture with alpha in iOS?

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm trying to use a video with alpha channel, but all I get is the alpha channel as color black.

I'm using the Vuforia video playback example.

I hope I'm not missing any relevant info.

Thanks in advance,
any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vuforia plays video by using the built-in system video players (on iOS and Android) by setting them to output to a render texture.

The system players do not support alpha channel video.

You need to apply a chroma-key shader on the render texture to remove say green or purple.

There is some discussion in the vuforia forums:

[playing-video-alpha-channel-videosample-demo-project](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/qcar-api/playing-video-alpha-channel-videosample-demo-project)

Comment: Thanks, I followed the link inside that URL :)

Comment: You can also render video with a library, see this other SO question for a qorking example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574801/ios-video-as-gl-texture-with-alpha-transparency/11713684#11713684

Comment: @Osuka42 would you post how did you done that? I am not able to play alpha video.Actually i wants to create a business card putting my picture on it and if scan i want to play the video. how can i do that?

Comment: @peterpt can you help me?

Comment: I posted another thread [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173928/how-to-play-an-alpha-video-in-unity-for-android)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a "special video" like the pic, in a power of two like: 256x512 format

[pic of special video to be used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xmSL.png)

Then use this custom shader:

```
Properties{ 
       _MainTex("Color (RGB)", 2D) = "white" 
  } 
  SubShader{ 
       Tags{ "Queue" = "Transparent" "RenderType" = "Transparent" } 
       CGPROGRAM 
       #pragma surface surf NoLighting alpha 
       fixed4 LightingNoLighting(SurfaceOutput s, fixed3 lightDir, fixed atten) { 
        fixed4 c; 
        c.rgb = s.Albedo; 
        c.a = s.Alpha; 
        return c; 
   } 
   struct Input { 
        float2 uv_MainTex; 
   }; 
   sampler2D _MainTex; 
   void surf(Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) { 
        o.Emission = tex2D(_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex).rgb; 

       if(IN.uv_MainTex.y <= 0.5){ 
          o.Alpha=0; 
       }

       else{ 
            o.Alpha = tex2D(_MainTex, float2(IN.uv_MainTex.x, IN.uv_MainTex.y-0.5)).rgb; 
       }

   } 
   ENDCG 
  } 
}
```

Also you can see my post in: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/833537/how-to-play-alpha-video-in-unity.html#answer-1094012

Comment: please check this thread. i posted a question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36173928/how-to-play-an-alpha-video-in-unity-for-android)